# Почему AUTORUN с флешки не запускается?

Tags: windows

```
[autorun] 
UseAutoPlay=1 
shellexecute=myprog.ехе

action=Запустить 
action=@myprog.ехе 
label=Flash
icon=myprog.ехе 
Shell\cmd1=Запустить 
Shell\cmd1\Command = myprog.ехе
```

Comment: Я очень плохо разбираюсь в этой теме, но есть мысль, что это мешает антивирус. Попробуйте с другим текстом в [autorun] к примеру, картинку поставьте (это то самое, что я умею делать).

Comment: Антивирус не мешает,он просто блокирует если вирус запускается при автозапуске.
В Windows 7 все запускается.
Совет:отформатируй флешку и не пиши левую фигню.

Answer (score 1):

В последних версиях Windows возможность автозапуска с флэшки (но не с CD-ROM) отключена. Это сделано из соображений безопасности. Поэтому вне зависимости от того, что написано в файле запуска, стартовать исполняемый exe не получится.

Comment: пруф?

Comment: Разве? ИМХО, они и автозапуск с CD-ROM отключили

Answer (score 0):

Это только до WinWista использовалось.
ХP была последней такой ОСью

Comment: в Windows XP SP3 эта фича тоже отключена

Comment: @shurik, нет, она там есть, только её можно вручную отключить...